# Slash Screen Android Studio desproporcionada

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy intentando crear un splash screen de una aplicación movil con Android Studio, el caso es que intento hacerlo con una imagen 2732x2732 ya que con ionic cordova simplemente hago el resources y me genera todas las versiones, sin embargo, intento hacerlo con android studio y se me visiona mal.
Actualmente la función la hace correctamente, sólo que no sé redimensionar la imagen.
No creo necesario adjuntar toda la APP, pero adjunto todo relacionado con el splash screen.

Gracias!

SplashActivity.java

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();


   }
}
```

Android Manifest.xml

```
  <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

styles.xlm

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

slash_screen.xlm

```
 <item>
    <bitmap
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />

</item>
```

Comment: Yo te aconsejaria que insertes un ImageView y vayas jugando con las dimensiones en height y widht hasta que encuentres mantener la relación con la pantalla.

Comment: La imagen tiene 2732x2732 píxels, la parte visible está en un cuadro central de 1200x1200 píxels. lo comento porque si hiciera un ImageView, se me vería toda la imagen y lo importante está en el centro, el resto es para llenar por pantallas más grandes. Tampoco entiendo el concepto de jugar con las dimensiones, ya que cada pantalla es una dimension, y se tendría que ver bien tanto en una tablet, como en un teléfono, o esa es mi intención

Comment: intenta añadir un  `android:scaleType="fitXY"/>` si no va pues, `android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>`

Comment: disculpa mi ignorancia, pero esto dónde tendría que añadirlo?

Comment: En esta porción de codigo `<item>
    <bitmap
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />

</item>`

Comment: Gracias, he probado ambos, pero no veo cambios en la imagen :(

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que la imagen tome el ancho del window debes especificar el width y height `match_parent` en vez de `wrap_content`